# Trazer o return de uma function para uma variável de uma outra function

Tags: javascript, html

gostaria de se há possibilidades de fazer isso:

```
function trazerNumero(){
    return 7;
}

function mostrarNumero(){
    numero = trazerNumero();
    alert(numero);
}



$(function(){
    mostrarNumero()
})
```

Sei que você vão falar que é melhor fazer um único método, mas no que eu quero não da para fazer isso, preciso pegar um valor que será gerado em uma outra function e usar em outra function.

Comment: Pode passar o retorno de `trazerNumero` como argumento para `mostrarNumero`.

Answer (score 2):

O que perguntas é perfeitamente válido e se testares [funciona](http://jsfiddle.net/nqnoodpg/).

Para teres código mais modular faria sentido, [como o renan disse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/91704/trazer-o-return-de-uma-function-para-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-de-uma-outra-function#comment185722_91704), passar o valor já como argumento assim:

```
function trazerNumero(){
    return 7;
}

function mostrarNumero(numero){
    alert(numero);
}

$(function(){
    var numero = trazerNumero();
    mostrarNumero(numero);
})
```

Comment: Mas na minha necessidade teria que ser assim, foi só um exemplo básico isso, mas deixa quieto consegui dar um jeito aqui. Obrigado!

Comment: @RomarioPires se explicares melhor o código que tens e não mostraste na pergunta posso ajudar mais e/ou dar ideias.